# Pub get RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Tags: flutter

I have problem with flutter 3.10.2 when i want use `flutter pub get` or `dart run`.
In other projects i don't have this problem.

this is error:

```
flutter pub get 
Resolving dependencies... (2.6s)
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
dart:core                                           List.[]
package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 334:47   PackageLister._checkSdkConstraint
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 277:32   PackageLister.incompatibilitiesFor
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 399:12   VersionSolver._choosePackageVersion
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 105:18   VersionSolver.solve.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 1374:14          HostedSource.withPrefetching.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/rate_limited_scheduler.dart 111:14  RateLimitedScheduler.withPrescheduling
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 1373:12          HostedSource.withPrefetching
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 101:14   VersionSolver.solve
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 358:14              Entrypoint.acquireDependencies
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:pub/src/command/get.dart 76:5               GetCommand.runProtected
```

pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.1 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0-nullsafety.0
  drop_shadow: ^0.1.0
  firebase_core: ^2.13.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.1
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_countdown_timer: ^4.1.0
  flutter_hms_gms_availability: ^3.7.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.6
  flutter_webrtc: ^0.9.31
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.8
  html: ^0.15.3
  http: ^0.13.6
  huawei_map: ^6.5.0+301
  i18n_extension: ^9.0.0
  lottie: ^2.3.2
  moor: ^4.6.0
  otp_autofill: ^2.1.0
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.15
  provider: ^6.0.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.1
  sqlite3_flutter_libs: ^0.5.15
  t4b_platform_auth:
    git:
      url: xxxxxxxx
  web_socket_channel: ^2.4.0

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.4.4
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  device_info_plus: ^9.0.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
  moor_generator: ^4.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to proceed by steps:

1. Close and reopen the IDE
2. Run `flutter clean`
3. Run `flutter pub outdated` to check your dependencies conflicts
4. Delete the `pubspec.lock` and run again `flutter pub get`

Be careful with url and stuff that could create errors in the formatting of your file